# Simplest way to query data contained in a delimited text file to populate a datagrid in VB.NET

Tags: sql, vb.net, linq, text, datatable

I'm trying to find the simplest and most robust method of running SQL-like queries against a large text file, and populating a datagrid. The text is delimited, and the pseudo-code for what I'm trying to do is:

```
table = parsed_text_file<br>
result = "SELECT CONCAT (first, last) AS name, COUNT(city) FROM table WHERE field = blah"<br>
DataGridView.DataSource = result
```

So far I have tried using:
1) `<OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & textfile & ";Extended Properties='text;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1;FMT=TabDelimited';")`
with OleDbDataAdapter and a SQL query to fill a dataset. This works well for the SQL part but I have had many issues with the db connection and delimiters and the Schema.ini

2) TextFieldParser to build a dataset. This works beautifully to read the file and create a table, but is a dog to query using only DataView, Select and/or RowFilter.

3) Parsing the file row-by-row and populating a dataset but this is very slow.

Before I get stuck into LINQ with datasets, surely there is an easier way to get this done?

Answer (score 0):

You could possible read your text file into a SQLite Database and then query that database with actual SQL.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22165/Using-SQLite-in-your-C-Application

Comment: This is helpful - I will look at SQLite, but would prefer a native method.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that the input was delimited, but didn't say how it was delimited. I have a series of posts and sample code illustrating using LINQ over dynamic types with CSV input files at http://www.thinqlinq.com/Post.aspx/Title/LINQ-to-CSV-using-DynamicObject-and-TextFieldParser. See if that helps in your case.

Comment: Thanks Jim - the text files are space delimited. Its looking like LINQ is the only way to go, its just annoying that there is no simple way of querying a dataset with a standard SQL query.

Comment: Since you have a header, you might be able to extend my sample by setting up the [TextFieldParser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx) to work with your input source.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how simple you want to be. You could read the csv and split it.

```
foreach(string[] line in File.ReadLines(fileName).Split(","))
{
    // do stuff with line
}
```

But that doesn't have any type information and it's prone to error, but if you want it quick and dirty then it's great.

There is also the `Microsoft Text Driver` which you can use with an `OdbcConnection`.

```
public OdbcConnection GetConnection(string filePath)
{
    // MaxScanRows set to 0 will scan the entire file before generating types
    var connectionString =  @"Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};" +
                            string.Format(@"Dbq={0};", filePath) +
                            @"Extensions=csv;MaxScanRows=0";

    var connection = new OdbcConnection(connectionString);
    return connection;
}

using(var connection = GetConnection(filePath))
{
    connection.Open();

    using(var command = new OdbcCommand("SELECT * FROM data.csv", connection))
    {
        using(var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            // Do stuff with reader
        }
    }
}
```

The cons with this approach is that it's a little complicated, the documentation for `Microsoft Text Driver` sucks, and it relies on Jet, but it produces a `DataReader` which can make consuming the data a lot easier.

Comment: This is a similar approach to my first (1) but thanks - I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin called SQL Plugin for Notepad++ that can do this.

Comment: can you help out with the link and how to install it?